# Symfony serializer - Deserialize xml to array of objects

Tags: php, symfony, xmlserializer, symfony-serializer

php Symfony serializer - Deserialize xml to array of objects

How deserialize xml with attributes to array of objects?

```
$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    <item flight="23"/>
    <item flight="24"/>
</response>';

        $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
        $metadataAwareNameConverter = new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory);

        $serializer = new Serializer(
            [new ArrayDenormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter)],
            [new XmlEncoder()]
        );
$objects = $serializer->deserialize($string, 'App\Entities\Item[]', 'xml');
```

Item class:

```
class Item
{
    #[SerializedName('@flight')]
    public string $flight;
}
```

Now result:

```
array:1 [
  "item" => App\Entities\Item
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enter the square brackets twice.

```php
$objects = $serializer->deserialize($string, 'App\Tests\Item[][]', 'xml')
```

[image]

Or the following. But it is basically the same thing.

```php
$xmlContent = '
    <response>
        <item flight="23"/>
        <item flight="24"/>
    </response>
';

class Item
{
    public string $flight;

    /**
     * @param string $flight
     */
    public function __construct(string $flight)
    {
        $this->flight = $flight;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFlight(): string
    {
        return $this->flight;
    }
}

$flights = [];
$encoders = [new XmlEncoder()];
$serializer = new Serializer([], $encoders);
$response = $serializer->decode($xmlContent, "xml");
foreach ($response['item'] as $item) {
    $flights[] = new Item($item['@flight']);
}
```

Comment: For simple decoding, you can not create a Serializer, but simply new XmlEncoder();